# IOS: Can't set left constraint for UITextField

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm having 1 UITextField , connected to my code.

```
@IBOutlet var txtFieldtest: UITextField!
```

I'm using constraint to set left/top position to it, it worked only with top, left position can't not be set.
Here is my code:

```
 self.txtFieldtest.sizeToFit()
 self.txtFieldtest.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

 let viewsDictionary = ["txtFieldTest":txtFieldtest]
 let view1_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[txtFieldTest(150)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

 let view1_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[txtFieldTest]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
 self.view.addConstraints(view1_constraint_H)
 self.view.addConstraints(view1_constraint_V)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "left position can't not be set"? What result does this code give you?

Comment: i already get left position just like storyboard result.